# Doxygen documentation variable

Tags: python-3.x, doxygen

I am creating design documentation with Doxygen and there is one issue I am facing every time.

This is my code:

```
## Function which returns list of project_kpi instances based on project_kpi.kpi_type_ID
## @param session: Session -> already created session
## @param kpi: project_kpi -> project_kpi instance which must have set project_kpi.kpi_type_ID
## @return list[project_kpi] -> list of found project_kpi (results per kpi type)
## @return None -> if no results were found
## @note Not in use
def select_project_kpi_by_kpi_type(session: Session, kpi: project_kpi) -> list[project_kpi] | None: ...
```

I would like to create variable (if it is even possible, but I saw that you can even type functions in Doxygen) which I can call in every function description.

Exactly this parameter:

```
## @param session: Session -> already created session
```

So the code could look like this:

```
## @my_var_name
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?. Question is a bit unclear but do you men  something like the `ALIASSES` setting or do you mean you want a link to another variable (maybe the `\ref` or `\see` command). Please explain.

Comment: aliasses I suppose.

Comment: @albert Version: 1.9.4

Comment: maybe also of interest `\snippet` and `\copybrief` / `\copydoc`. Note current doxygen version is 1.9.6